# Polar decomposition of an already symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices

Suppose the matrix F can be decomposed into orthogonal and symmetric parts $F = RU$ where R is the orthogonal matrix and U the symmetric one.

If I suppose that $F$ is symmetric by default does that imply that $F = U $ ? I tried to prove that but I am stuck here:

$$ F^T = (RU)^T = UR^T= F$$
$$ RU = UR^T  $$
$$ RUR = U$$

But I am not able to extract any useful conclusion from the last equation.
Thanks.

EDIT: if F=U for symmetric F is not generally true, then on what conditions would it be true? I have solved a few exercises where they are the same...

Comment: No, the decomposition you mentioned is not what ‘polar decomposition’ refers to and it is not unique. E.g. $I=I^2=(-I)^2=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}^2$. In a polar decomposition, one of the multiplicands is orthogonal while the other is positive semidefinite. The polar decomposition of a nonsingular matrix is unique.

Comment: I am using one of the definitions found in the wiki entry https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition.     " The polar decomposition can also be defined as A=PU where P is symmetric positive-definite but is in general a different matrix, while U is the same matrix as above." More specifically, it is the one used in continuum mechanics, where the deformation gradient is decomposed into a rotation matrix and a symmetric stretch tensor, which can be right of left